# .head() and .tail() with negative indexes on pandas GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having trouble with filtering all but the last 1 element in each group of groupby object of pandas.DataFrame:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 3]], 
                 columns=['A', 'B'])
g = x.groupby('A')
```

As expected (according to [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html)) `g.head(1)` returns

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  1
```

whereas `g.head(-1)` returns empty DataFrame

From the behavior of `x.head(-1)` I'd expect it to return

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  1
2  a  2
3  b  2
```

i.e. dropping the last element of each group and then merging it back into the dataframe. If that's just the bug in pandas, I'd be grateful to anyone who suggests an alternative approach.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9214

Comment: thank you, failed to find it. however the suggested workaround (.apply) screws up the index in the resulting DF, can you point me at how to return to the integer-based indexing after .apply'ing?

Comment: g.apply(lambda x: x.head(-1)).reset_index(drop=True) seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented these haven't (yet) been implemented in pandas. However, you can use cumcount to implement them efficiently:

```
def negative_head(g, n):
    return g._selected_obj[g.cumcount(ascending=False) >= n]

def negative_tail(g, n):
    return g._selected_obj[g.cumcount() >= n]

In [11]: negative_head(g, 1)  # instead of g.head(-1)
Out[11]:
   B
0  1
1  1
2  2
3  2
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @TomAugspurger, it is an open bug in pandas and g.apply(lambda x: x.head(-1)) is able to emulate the needed logic, however the result becomes:

```
    A  B
A        
a 0  a  1
  2  a  2
b 1  b  1
  3  b  2
```

but after that one can apply `.reset_index(drop=True)` (mind drop=True here) and that returns

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  1
3  b  2
```

So, the current workaround is `g.apply(lambda x: x.head(-1)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Just the usual apply warning, this can be slow (that's why we special cased groupby head to use cumcount under the hood, at least originally not 100% sure if it still does). :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Pandas [version 1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) negative head has been supported. I just wanted to let  people know since I landed here when looking into the matter.

> df.head(-n)