# Looking to drop first 5 rows of dataframe after ever new value occurs

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am looking to drop the first 5 rows each time a new value occurs in a dataframe

```
data = {
'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am looking to drop the first 5 rows after each new value. Ex: 'A' value is new... delete first 5 rows. Now encounter 'B' value... delete its first 5 rows...

Comment: Are the values in `col1` already grouped. For example, is it possible to have different group of `A`s later after other values?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following:

```
mask = df.groupby('col1').cumcount() >= 5
df = df.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative `tail`:

```
df.groupby('col1').tail(-5)
```

To group by consecutive values:

```
group = df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(group).tail(-5)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
5     A     6
6     A     7
12    B    13
13    B    14
19    C    20
20    C    21
```

*NB. As pointed out by @Mark, there is an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9214) for older pandas versions (<1.4), in which case the `cumcount` approach can be used.*

Comment: FWIW, there has been a bug bouncing around on the pandas repo for years around negative values in `tail()` applied to groups. You may need a relatively recens version of pandas for this to work (it didn't work for me in 1.3.4, but does in 1.4.2).

Comment: @Mark interesting... what'd be the workaround in versions prior to 1.4?

Comment: @JonClements [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9214) links to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783072/head-and-tail-with-negative-indexes-on-pandas-groupby-object/33783944#33783944). There was also a more [recent issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30192)